# Concern with HtmlPage object not cleaned up

Tags: java, memory-management, exception, htmlunit

In this example of HtmlUnit, I have cleanup the HtmlPage, still I am getting the anchors of the specified url in the main method, as I am thinking in this code that the return statement is computed first and then the finally called and then the computed page above is returned from getPageResource() method or if you think other than this please share.

but one more concern in my mind that if object got clean up referenced by "page" then it will get available to getAnchors from it.

```
public HtmlPage getPageResource() {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = null;
        try {
            page = webClient.getPage("http://some-url.com");
            // Do something with page
            return page;
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return page;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return page;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return page;
        } finally {
            if (page != null)
                page.cleanUp();
        }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    HtmlUnitExample htmlUnitExample = new HtmlUnitExample();
    HtmlPage page = htmlUnitExample.getPageResource();
    System.out.println(page.getAnchors());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some comments about this code.

Firstly, if the `getPage` throws any exception then the `page` variable will be `null` while if it doesn't it will have an object assigned. So in the `Do something with page` line you are 100% sure that `page` is not `null`. So you should place your code in there. That includes the `cleanUp`.

Furthermore, when an exception is detected you're returning a `null` object and then you are trying to `getAnchors` from a `null` object. That will result in a `NullPointerException` in your `main` method.

You're most likely looking for something like this:

```
public HtmlPage getPageResource() throws Exception {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://some-url.com");
    // Do something with page
    page.cleanUp();
    return page;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    HtmlUnitExample htmlUnitExample = new HtmlUnitExample();
    try {
        HtmlPage page = htmlUnitExample.getPageResource();
        System.out.println(page.getAnchors());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is simpler and there are no `if` statements. Most likely the whole `getPageResource()` method should be removed or maybe, instead of returning a page, return a list of anchors (with anchors or empty) so that you can fully trust you have a `List` in your `main` and you don't need any exception handling in there.

That was about Java. Turning to HtmlUnit, I've never needed to use a `cleanUp`. The very same JavaDocs state `you should probably never need to call it directly` so, the obvious question is *What are you trying to do with it?*. If you want to be ready to fetch a new page with that object, bear in mind there is no need to clean the page.

Comment: My friend, firstly I am 100% sure that page is not null, as I am getting the anchors from the page in the main function and Secondly I would like to explicitly trigger cleanUp method to clean my HtmlPage objects, but I m saying I m still getting the anchors from it after calling cleanUp on it

Comment: As in my application based on HtmlUnit there is memory-leak, so I have used profiler and  Jconsole to identify that what objects are alive in the memory and I find that there are many HtmlPage objects, so here I posted an example that is somewhat similar to one function of my system, only I have to focus is on cleanUp not on how to code, I have already coded that this is just a sample example to cleanUp, so I am struggling in cleanUp and still confusing that Objects are not going to cleanUp after explicitly triggering cleanUp on those like in above

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to set the page to null instead of cleanUp it for memory concerns? Or, i suggest you add 'Thread.sleep(10*1000);' after statement '//Do something with the page', as the loading of the page is asynchronized. I guess when you trigger cleanUp, the page is not yet loaded.